# Call Fragmentwith NotificationManager android

Tags: android, crash, push-notification, fragment

I have a fragment that shows a DialogFragment with a TimePicker, a I set the time, y when shows a notificationManager, I need when I Push the notification it sends me to other fragment, but de app crashes.

How can I do that?

Thank you (y)

Comment: What's the crash? Can you attach the logs? Another thing, you can't use a DialogFragment without activity.. So you have to call it from within an activity.

Comment: the app close... yes, Ihave 2 dialogFragment's , and work, but when I push the notification the app closes

Comment: What does it show on the logs?